# How to reflect changes in a project, which is done in same type of project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Project A in java using Eclipse i modified code and I have no version control or CVS on it.

Now I have Project A'. I want to apply changes that i have done in A to A'. where A & A' are same work with smaller modifications.

I tried to take a patch , but i am not finding any option in eclipse

Can I know how this can be done with changing each and every file which i modified in A.

Note: The work I made in Project A is highly compatible in A'

Comment: try using `diff`.  Look at the date modified on the files.

Comment: I'm taking a guess since I'm not too familiar with java but couldn't you import into the build path as a library ? Depends a bit on how you made your classes of course.

Comment: This is actually a good question. It's easy to do with source control, but I haven't imagined doing it manually without it.

Comment: any tools to do this task??

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing EGit from Eclipse marketplace.